# Creating subtitles in QML with background and vertical wrapping

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I am making a video player app using QML.

I am currently having issues implementing subtitles with QML.

My current code for the subtitles is:

```
Rectangle {
    id: nativeSubtitles
    height: nativeSubs.font.pixelSize + 4
    visible: true
    anchors.left: controlsBar.left
    anchors.right: controlsBar.right
    anchors.bottom: progressBar.top
    radius: 5
    color: "transparent"

    Label {
        id: nativeSubs
        width: parent.width
        text: "SUBTITLES! OWO YESH f rre e er erwwew we wewe ew ew ew eew ewew ew ewwe3wwe ew "
        color: "white"
        font.family: notoFont.name
        font.pixelSize: 24
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        opacity: 1
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "orange"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work as I want it to.

How I want the subtitles to work is they are centered between left and right and bottom of `controlsbar`.

If the subtitles grow to be too large to fit within the width of it, the text should split and add another line to grow vertically, still however anchored to the bottom of controlsbar.

The background should only occupy the areas where the text is occupied with a outside padding of 2.

How should I do this? I've been spending ages pulling my hair out trying to get things to work...

EDIT: New code with fixed vertical wrapping thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52955752/10547967

```
Rectangle {
    id: nativeSubtitles
    height: nativeSubs.font.pixelSize + 4
    visible: true
    anchors.left: controlsBar.left
    anchors.right: controlsBar.right
    anchors.bottom: progressBar.top
    radius: 5
    color: "transparent"

    Label {
        id: nativeSubs
        width: parent.width
        text: "SUBTITLES! OWO YESH f rre e er erwwew we wewe ew ew ew eew ewew ew ewwe3wwe ew "
        color: "white"
        font.family: notoFont.name
        font.pixelSize: 24
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.top
        opacity: 1
        wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere

        background: Rectangle {
            color: "orange"
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
        }
    }
}
```

Now all that needs to be fixed is for the background to only be the width of the text when the text doesn't take up the full width of the space between the controlsbar left and right anchors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Label` property `wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere`

```
wrapMode : enumeration
```

Set this property to wrap the text to the Text item's width. The text will only wrap if an explicit width has been set. wrapMode can be one of:

```
Text.NoWrap (default) - no wrapping will be performed. If the text contains insufficient newlines, then contentWidth will exceed a set width.
Text.WordWrap - wrapping is done on word boundaries only. If a word is too long, contentWidth will exceed a set width.
Text.WrapAnywhere - wrapping is done at any point on a line, even if it occurs in the middle of a word.
Text.Wrap - if possible, wrapping occurs at a word boundary; otherwise it will occur at the appropriate point on the line, even in the middle of a word.
Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
```

from [Text QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop)

[2nd **UPDATE**]

### There are two ways

1. You can use `TextMetrics` element (**requires QtQuick 2.5**)

   ```
   TextMetrics {
                      id:     t_metrics
                      font:   nativeSubs.font
                      text:   nativeSubs.text
                  }

   Rectangle {
       id: nativeSubtitles
       height: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height
       visible: true
       anchors.left: controlsBar.left
       anchors.right: controlsBar.right
       anchors.bottom: progressBar.top
       radius: 5
       color: "transparent"

       Label {
           id: nativeSubs
           width: parent.width
           text: "SUBTITLES! OWO YESH f rre e er erwwew we wewe ew ew ew eew ewew ew ewwe3wwe ew "
           wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
           color: "white"
           font.pixelSize: 24

           renderType: Text.NativeRendering
           horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
           opacity: 1

           background : Rectangle {
               color: "orange"
               anchors.left: parent.left
               anchors.right: parent.right
               height: t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height
           }
       }
   }
   ```

2.You can use your **nativeSubtitles Rectangle's property** [childrenRect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childrenRect-prop) i.e `nativeSubtitles.childrenRect.height + p` ( `p`: some padding)

Just replace in the code above `t_metrics.tightBoundingRect.height` with `nativeSubtitles.childrenRect.height + p`

### [For an adaptive rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9f8w.gif)

[image: qml subtitles]

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


Window {
    id: bigWin
    objectName: 'bigWin'
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "#000000"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        id:subtitlesBar
        color:"black"
        border.width: 3
        border.color: "#ba2121"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: barRect.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left

        RowLayout {
            id: nativeSubtitles
            visible: true
            anchors.left: subtitlesBar.left
            anchors.right: subtitlesBar.right
            height: childrenRect.height
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10



            Rectangle{
                id:theBoss
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight:  true
                Layout.rightMargin:  50
                Layout.leftMargin: 50
                Layout.maximumWidth:  nativeSubtitles.width
                color:"transparent"
                height: childrenRect.height

                Label {
                    id: nativeSubs

                    // Monitor the width
                    onWidthChanged:  {

                        if(width > parent.width -50 )
                            width=parent.width -50
                    }
                    onTextChanged:if (width<=parent.width -50) width=undefined
                    text: inPut.text
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
                    font.pixelSize: 24
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    opacity: 1
                    background: Rectangle {
                        id : orgnOne
                        color: "orange"
                        opacity: 0.5
                        width: theBoss.childrenRect.width
                        height: theBoss.childrenRect.height
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: barRect
        height: 2
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.bottom: inPut.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
    }

    TextInput{
        id:inPut
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        height: 60
        color: "#2d9604"
        font.pointSize: 14
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! That has solved the issue of the text expanding upwards. Now I just need it so if the text is smaller than the available width, the background will be only the width of the text, not the whole available width.

Comment: @KittehNamedKitten Next time organize your questions because I'm answering two in one and not getting the answer marked .**CHECK THE UPDATED ANSWER ** and you're welcome ;)

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-label.html#background-prop

Comment: added before update pics and clarification with shorter text before.

Comment: Also, i'm using quickcontrols2.

Comment: @KittehNamedKitten Please next time when asking questions include your **DEV environment ** ie OS, Qt version ....etc

Comment: It's the width for the background that needs changing not the height. Should I change it to width instead?

Comment: @KittehNamedKitten if we are wrapping text also the height changes , so I think you need to handle both

Comment: @KittehNamedKitten and what's the max size of subtitles ?

Comment: @KittehNamedKitten [Subtitles](https://pasteboard.co/HKeNGEwU.gif)  is this what you want ????

Comment: @KittehNamedKitten check the updated answer at the end ,try it and get inspired ;)

Comment: Thanks so much. There are still a few issues though. I updated the subs in https://github.com/NamedKitten/KittehPlayer/commit/7e2aea044f3ec361e8e65b51c86f05bf0c4e1352 but they still have the issue of being too wide when more than 1 line high. I can't screenshot ATM so if you want to test you'll either need to build it manually (and also compile libmpv) or boot up into a linux distro and try the AppImage in releases.